# Mockito + TestNG + String - test not working without autowired

Tags: java, spring, mockito, testng, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing unit test for an web app, and I've got problem with service layer. App is using Spring Data JPA, and H2 database for tests.

Here is my test class:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfiguration.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
@Transactional
public class AuthorCreateServiceTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

@Mock
private AuthorRepository authorRepository;

private AuthorCreateServiceImpl authorCreateServiceImpl;

private Author firstAuthor;
private Author secondAuthor;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() {
    authorCreateServiceImpl = new AuthorCreateServiceImpl(authorRepository);
    firstAuthor = new Author();
    firstAuthor.setFirstName("Leo");
    firstAuthor.setLastName("Manly");
    firstAuthor.setNationality("Mexico");
    firstAuthor.setId(3L);
    secondAuthor = new Author();
    secondAuthor.setFirstName("Zorro");
    secondAuthor.setLastName("Plata");
    secondAuthor.setNationality("Zambia");
    secondAuthor.setId(4L);
}

@Test
public void succesfullySaveAuthorTest() {
    Author testAuthor = authorCreateServiceImpl.create(firstAuthor);
    Assert.assertEquals(testAuthor.getFirstName(), firstAuthor.getFirstName());
}

@Test
public void failSavingAuthorTest() {
    String firstName = "Man";
    Author testAuthor = authorCreateServiceImpl.create(secondAuthor);
    boolean isEqual = testAuthor.getFirstName().equals(firstName);
    Assert.assertFalse(isEqual);
}

}
```

In this state `testAuthor` is null, but repository and `createService` objects exist. But if I add an `Autowired` annotation to the `AutrhorCreateServiceImpl` field, it works fine.

Is the `Autowired` necessary or I'm doing something wrong?

EDIT

TestConfiguration class

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.altkom.library"} )
@Configuration
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
public class TestConfiguration extends JPAConfiguration {

public TestConfiguration(Environment environment) {
    super(environment);
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    EmbeddedDatabase dataBase = builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).addScript("classpath:import.sql").build();
    return dataBase;
}
}
```

Comment: Would you show the TestConfiguration.class, I suspect you are not scanning so the AuthorCreateServiceImpl  gets picked up by the spring container.

Comment: The issue is probably that you haven't stubbed anything in your mock `AuthorRepository´ so that it returns null. It's hard to verify that this is the issue though since we can't run your test case due to missing classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to obtain bean from spring-context, this annotation is required. 
In your implementation you've created a service with a mocked repository. Mocked objects return null by default. You can use `Mockito.when()` to override default behaviour.